# the sequence of execution of Makefile

Tags: makefile

For a Makefile like this:

```
HOSTARCH := $(shell uname -u | sed -e s/i.86/i386/)    
HOSTOS := $(shell uname -s | tr '[:upper:]''[:lower:]')         
export HOSTARCH HOSTOS      

unconfig:
          @rm -f $(obj)include/config.h

versatilepb_config: unconfig
@board/versatile/split_by_variant.sh $@
```

when I tape " make versatilepb_config", where would it begin to execute? from the beginning or from "versatilepb_config"? we get the value of HOSTARCH,HOSTOS right now or not? Then how could I print the value of HOSTOS/HOSTARCH in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The make build system is not executing sequentially (1st line, 2nd line, etc).

When you do `make versatilepb_config`, it will execute in this order:

- set global variables (`HOSTARCH` and `HOSTOS` in your case)
- find the rule `versatilepb_config`
- then it will find pre-required rule `unconfig`
- then it will execute `@rm -f $(obj)include/config.h`
- then it will execute `@board/versatile/split_by_variant.sh $@`

If anything fails, it will stop at that step.

So, if you want to print values from the `unconfig` step, just add it there:

```
unconfig:
          @rm -f $(obj)include/config.h
          echo $HOSTARCH
          echo $HOSTOS
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I tried several times and found the lines about HOSTOS, HOSTARCH have been executed every time. I tried to write to a new file by "echo $(HOSTOS) >> hostos.txt" and the content increased everytime.

Comment: And if the commands to verify HOSTOS/HOSTARCH havenot been executed, the printed content would always be empty, right? :)

Comment: @MingZhao Do you mean this : `HOSTARCH := $(shell uname -u | sed -e s/i.86/i386/)`? I modified my answer. That is executed every time you run that makefile. Or, do you ask something else?

Comment: In fact I just want to know which part in Makefile will be executed. There are normally two types of commands, one is like "versatile_config" which would be executed if we tape this pattern in the console, and another type like "HOSTARCH := ... ". For the second type, will il exexute everytime? no matter we type "make versatilepb_config" or "make" ?? dose "make" mean "make all" or this command will execute every line in Makefile if the condition is satisfied?

Comment: I think I found the answer: the symble ":=" means immediate assignement, so in my case they are assigend the first time I call make. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles

Comment: @MingZhao Yes, those will execute every time, regardless which rule you chose (all, versatilepb_config, or any else). `make all` search for the rule `all`, which you do not have.